# How do I get WordPress to show the full list of installable languages?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

When I go to "Settings >> General >> Site Language" I can select the language for the WordPress admin interface. This list is divided into two parts. The first part lets me choose among the already installed languages. The second part of the list lets me choose a language that is not installed, and WordPress will download the language files for me.

However, I have noticed that the second part of the list (i.e. the one that shows the list of installable languages) is sometimes not there. I imagine that there is a setting somewhere or so that makes all the languages show up, but I don't know which settings it is.

So my question is: How do I get the full list of installable languages show up under "Settings >> General >> Site Language"?

Comment: The full list is pulled from the remote API, so perhaps when that list is not present there's been a network issue, at your end or at theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that WordPress files are owned by www-data. Use chown if you are on a local machine. If your installation is online, and you can ssh, use chown as well, of not use the control panel to change ownership.